# Why is my Model.where() returning a blank array (when I'm sure there are matches)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What am I doing incorrectly that is giving me a blank array from this command?

```
Item.where(:load_date => Date.today + 2)
```

Here is my Rails Console:

```
.9.3-p194 :024 > Item.first.load_date
Item Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" LIMIT 1
=> Fri, 24 May 2013 
1.9.3-p194 :025 > Item.where(:load_date => Date.today + 2)
Item Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."load_date" = '2013-05-24'
=> []
1.9.3-p194 :026 > Item.first.load_date == Date.today + 2
Item Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" LIMIT 1
=> true
```

Item Model:

```
... 
#  load_date       :date
...

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :bt_num, :dept, :formula, :item_code, :load_date, :prod_comments, :qc_comments, :qc_tech, :qty_in_kg, :qty_in_liters, :rm_ok_by, :series, :status, :time_to_produce, :vat
...
```

Comment: What is value of `load_date` in the database?

Comment: What is your database? I've tested here on mysql and it worked

Comment: Datebase is sqlite3. Item.first.load_date == Fri, 24, May 2013 and class is 'Date'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1474238/976775 may help

Comment: It is not the database, I've tested it on Postgres, Mysql and Sqlite, it worked perfectly. Maybe it is related to timezone? Try to `Item.where(:load_date => Date.today + 1)` and `Item.where(:load_date => Date.today + 3)` and check if still doesn't work

Comment: Blank array for both. The part that's blowing my mind is how Item.first.load_date == Date.today + 2 is *true* but it's not showing up  with .where()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these

```
Item.where(:load_date => (Date.today + 2).strftime)
  or 
Item.where("Date(load_date) =?", (Date.today + 2).strftime)
```

Comment: The second one works but not the first (first still returns blank). Why would the formatting of the date matter?? And why wouldn't the first work??

Comment: load_date is the column of datetime but we want only Date from there so I used Date(load_date).... and strftime used because it will convert (Date.today+2) to the format "2013-05-24" and in database values are saved as "2013-05-24 12:12" instead of "fridat May 24, 2013 "

Comment: Why wouldn't Item.first.load_date show me "2013-05-24 12:12" instead of "Fri, 24 May 2013"? When I check the class of Item.first.load_date, it is also 'Date'. I appreciate the help, I'm just trying to understand what's going on.

Comment: Then try this... Item.where("load_date=?", (Date.today + 2).strftime)