# Good design for incrementing / decrementing week view of a to do list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**I am looking for advice on how to design a web app that shows a week view for a todo list.**

The current layout is a table with days of the week as columns with items to be done listed below. I have gotten something functional by calculating the header dates in the controller with:

```
@week_starting = Date.today.at_beginning_of_week if @week_starting.blank?
```

Other weekday headers are shown by incrementing @week_starting.

I have created individual instance variables such as @to_do_on_mon, @to_do_on_tue, etc. to show what is to be done that day (and then iterate through them to list out the items).
Here is an example of one:

```
@to_do_on_mon = BatchTicket.where("Date(load_date) =?", @week_starting.strftime
```

**How would you improve on this design to easily increment/decrement the week shown and list out items to be done?**

Comment: the only resolution you have is a week? if that is so, you can save the year, week number in that year and a day in a year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, just a personal preference, but I think it would make the code nicer changing the first line to this:

```
@week_starting ||= Date.today.at_beginning_of_week
```

It's shorter and it's clearer.

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do with the `Date(load_date)` there, but since you have ActiveSupport available, I would probably do something more readable like this:

```
@to_do_on_mon = BatchTicket.where date: (@week_starting + 0.days)
@to_do_on_tue = BatchTicket.where date: (@week_starting + 1.days)
# etc.
```

Or, depending on what your page/app looks like, you can do it in one query if you need to:

```
BatchTicket.where('your date range').group_by { |b| b.date.strftime("%u") }
```

Will return an array grouped into days (1..7).

Hope that helps

Comment: Good suggestion on ||=. Already done. As for the Date(load_date) bit, that's the ONLY means I've discovered to accurately locate my items by date (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682526/why-is-my-model-where-returning-a-blank-array-when-im-sure-there-are-matches). Any suggestions on how to update the week shown?

Comment: Oh, I've missed that question. I'm not sure I understood what 'increment/decrement the week' means though - You would like to show a week view, and then paginate between weeks?

Comment: What I mean is that I have my current table that I calculate the headers using @week_starting and then increment it to show Tues, Wed, etc. I have two icons < > that I would like to show the previous / next week when clicked, meaning 'week_starting' would have to -/+ 7 days and then refresh the page. I'm also open to using AJAX but thought I would get this working first to learn how.

Comment: You cuold use an ajax call to update the table's data (that you would probably store in a JSON on the initial call) - that would the faster approach. You could also use a normal GET request that will return all of the data. The advantage of that is that users could bookmark/share the link for a specific week.

Comment: Do you know of any links that would describe either of those approaches? Thanks!