# How to sort a two-dimensional array (2d array) by date in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a two dimensional array which has following structure

```
array = [
          ["2019-03-11","00986587","LBP"],
          ["2019-02-23","00462421","USD"],
          ["2019-05-26","00357853","EUR"],
          ["2019-09-15","00357382","LBP"]
        ]
```

I want to sort the array based on the date (first element of each row).

Looking for the following result:

```
array = [
          ["2019-09-15","00357382","LBP"],
          ["2019-05-26","00357853","EUR"],
          ["2019-03-11","00986587","LBP"],
          ["2019-02-23","00462421","USD"]
        ]
```

After my research on **sort** and **sort_by** i didn't find any solution.
Can anyone please help me to solve my problem ? and thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort 2d arrays with [sort_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) method: `sort_by` sorts in ascending order by default. If you want it to be in descending order, just reverse the result.

```
array.sort_by{ |a| a.first }.reverse
```

Comment: I tried it now, but it didn't work, nothing changed in the array, still having the same. @demir

Comment: @JosephNehme This code returns an array. You need to reassign the returned value to the `array` variable. Try this: `array = array.sort_by{ |a| a.first }.reverse`

Comment: @JosephNehme If you want to mutate the current array use `sort_by!` and `reverse!` instead.

Comment: `sort_by { |a| a.first }` could also be written as `sort_by(&:first)`

Comment: You don't even need to use `sort_by`. Arrays are sorted by their first elements anyway (and then by their second elements, ...).

Comment: ^ Meaning `array.sort.reverse` would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Two important notes:

- your dates are written in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, so sorting them alphabetically will also sort them chronologically.
- your dates are the first element in the arrays, and array are sorted by their first element first.

It means that all you need is:

```
array.sort.reverse
#=> => [["2019-09-15", "00357382", "LBP"], ["2019-05-26", "00357853", "EUR"], ["2019-03-11", "00986587", "LBP"], ["2019-02-23", "00462421", "USD"]]
```

If you want to save modify `array` in place, you can write:

```
array.sort!.reverse!
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to convert the string to a `Date` object and use it for sorting:

```
Date.strptime("2019-09-15", '%Y-%m-%d').class
#=> Sun, 15 Sep 2019
```

See [Rails ActiveSupport Time Parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354657/rails-activesupport-time-parsing)

---

So, if you want to change the original array, use [Array#sort!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Array.html#method-i-sort-21), note the bang (`!`):

```
array.sort! { |(date_1, *rest_1), (date_2, *rest_2)| Date.strptime(date_2, '%Y-%m-%d') <=> Date.strptime(date_1, '%Y-%m-%d') }
array
#=> [["2019-09-15", "00357382", "LBP"], ["2019-05-26", "00357853", "EUR"], ["2019-03-11", "00986587", "LBP"], ["2019-02-23", "00462421", "USD"]]
```

Change the block for inverse order:

```
Date.strptime(date_1, '%Y-%m-%d') <=> Date.strptime(date_2, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

---

Note that for the block variables I used the `*splat` operator which works like this:

```
ary = [1,2,3]
a, *b = ary
p a, b
# 1
# [2, 3]
```